# Html - Cannot load external http.jpg as image source

Tags: html, image, http, jpeg

I want to load this external jpg in my webpage:

"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxMjgxNTk0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIyOTg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg"

If I copy the link and put it in my chrome Browser, it opens the Poster. 
But if I put it as a img src it does not load if I empty my cache before:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
          <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="no picture!" id="bild" height="400px"/>
      </body>
    </html>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the following error:

> **Referral Denied**
> You don't have permission to access "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxMjgxNTk0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIyOTg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg" on this server.

This sounds like they are checking the [`Referer:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.36) header sent by the web browser to determine whether the image is requested from one of their own web pages or from an external web page.

The [IMDb Conditions of Use](http://www.imdb.com/conditions) contains the following:

> **Framing:** You may not frame or utilize framing techniques to enclose any trademark, logo, or other proprietary information (including images, text, page layout, or form) of IMDb without express written consent.

While you're welcome to link to IMDb's *web pages* (with appropriate attribution), I'm guessing that they don't want you to link directly to their *images* from your own web pages.